# dplyr: How to apply the same filter to all variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am sure there must be a better way to do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(X1 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X2 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X3 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X4 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X5 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X6 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X7 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X8 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X9 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X10 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X11 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X12 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X13 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X14 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X15 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X16 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X17 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X18 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X19 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) &
           X20 %in% c(0,1,2,5,10) )
```

Comment: I would probably just melt to long, filter, and cast back to wide. Care to share a reproducible example?

Comment: Could use `apply` - something like `df[apply(df, 1, function(x) all(sapply(x, function(y) y %in% c(0, 1, 2, 5, 10)))), ]` should work.

Comment: Another variant with `apply`: `df[apply(apply(df,2,function(x) x %in% c(0,1,2,5,10)),1,sum)==length(df),]`, it should work as well.

Comment: @Zach It does, thanks. You may post it as an answer.

Comment: Something different: `df[Reduce("&", Map(function(x) x %in% c(0,1,2,5,10), df)),]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments above, the following works.

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) all(sapply(x, function(y) y %in% c(0, 1, 2, 5, 10)))), ]
```